# "Cannot launch without an active device" although I set up an Android emulator?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I'm trying to learn flutter and want to run a test app I'm writing with Visual Studio Code. Although I set up an Android emulator it doesn't seem to recognise it. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you see the device name on bottom right corner?

Comment: Hi aoiTenshi... nope, it says No device... but the emulator is running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Run flutter doctor` and flutter devices, if no devices appear to be connected (in this case, emulated) you need to kill the`adb server`, open the emulator and then start the `adb-server`.

kill server using --> `adb kill-server` command
Start server--> `adb start-server`

If the issue still persists after this, try `flutter doctor --android licenses`

And if it still continues, please post your flutter doctor & flutter devices output.
If above not works,
try those:

- Disabled and Enabled Flutter plugin
- Disabled and Enabled Dart plugin
- Restarted Vscode
- Restarted PC

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I was missing the Android SDK Command-line Tools. Now updating and then checking the licenses...

Comment: When I try to enable Android for the project it returns the following message: 
Cannot create a project within the Flutter SDK. Target directory 'C:\Dev-Tools\Source\flutter\ÜbungsProjekt\übungsprojekt' is within the Flutter SDK at 'C:\Dev-Tools\Source\flutter'.
exit code 2
So, how do I change the target directory?

Comment: Alright, I finally got it. I'm quite a noob, as you clearly noticed, so thanks for all your useful help. It got me there.